# Interrupted Dialogue

Tags: punctuation

In English, an em-dash is often used where dialogue is interrupted:

> Get into the c—

Is there an equivalent punctuation in Japanese?

Comment: In the novel that I'm currently reading ― (horbar) is used in similar fashion, but more instead of ellipsis, e.g. after full word, than such use (though I don't remember seeing such em-dash in english texts, usualy there also ellipsis).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either a 3点リーダー or a dash is used for this purpose. Note that a Japanese dash is usually longer than an English em-dash.

[image]

The last example (leaving a Latin consonant) is fairly unconventional, but it can express the suddenness nicely, and you may see it in casual light novels, blogs and such.

See also:

- [Is Japanese em dash equal to Latin em dash?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36601/5010)
- [Ellipsis Usage and Format](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18058/5010)